# SSRS visual studio asking credentials while Deploying reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have built SSRS reports in visual studio on Azure VM and configured webportal url in the project properties but when I am trying to deploy my reports SSRS visual studio getting a Reporting Services login prompt to enter username and password while Deploying reports. I Have entered VM admin credentials, DB credentials but nothing is working.
Please help I am not able to deploy any changes to the report since few days.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the first time you have published a report to a report server since set you set the deployment property TargetServerURL for a project, verify that the server name includes server and not reports. For example, https://localhost/reportserver, and not
https://localhost/reports. Specifying the reports directory on the local server instead of the reportserver directory indirectly causes this dialog box to open.